# Query shows SELECT 0

Tags: sql-server, performance, heap

I'm looking through the queries being executed by a third party application. The application was flagged as being slow by some of our end-users.

It seems to `INSERT` records into a HEAP, then `DELETE` them again after the session ends (without any selects happening on them?)
But at the end of each `INSERT` statement there is a `SELECT 0`.

Am I seeing some kind of artifact from the query plan cache? Is it possible there is some parameter that's missing? All other parameters are clearly indicated as for example `@P1`.

There are 350 `INSERT`actions per minute and a `DELETE` of everything in the table ever hour. Which seems to be an OK case to use a HEAP, however if this SELECT 0 is actually selecting something from this heap, I'm wondering if I should ad a clustered index.

Update: Added a screenshot to show the select:
[image: SelectWithoutQuery]

Comment: `DELETE of everything in the table ever hour.` If the table is not referenced by foreign key to any other tables, then a truncate would be much bet

Comment: SELECT 0 could be used as some type of confirmation of the records that were inserted without actually selecting the columns.  Good luck figuring out *why* an application is doing that.

Comment: @Kin unfortunately I don't have access to the application, which is doing the deletions.

Comment: @MaxVernon How would that work exactly? When I run SELECT 0 all I'm getting back is... 0?

Comment: surely it is not only `SELECT 0` ???  If so, that is totally useless; I assumed you meant something like `SELECT 0 FROM schema.table...` and just didn't include the unnecessary details.

Comment: @MaxVernon As far as the query plan cache shows, theres an insert, followed immediately by SELECT 0. Which the query plan shows as SELECT WITHOUT QUERY. If I edit the query from the plan cache, it just shows INSERT ... (parameters) then 5 empty rows, followed by SELECT 0. Which in my eyes looks totally useless, and very confusing. (no data left out, no FROM clause in there)

Comment: @Reaces  `Select 0` might be a part of library that the application uses to access database. It can be used , for instance, to check connectivity .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An execution plan is only going to have the code that was last compiled and used, to my knowledge. In troubleshooting applications myself I have come across where a statement I was looking at through the execution plan was actually written with `sp_executesql` and so was dynamic T-SQL that contained a bit more logic than the end result.

You don't specify the version you are working with but I would suggest using a server-side trace or Extended Event session to map out the sequence of commands being passed so you fully understand what is being done in your situation.

My first thought is the application (or the developer) wrote the insert statement and in some form or fashion is doing a check on something (i.e. maybe errors). In that check if it is good they are simply passing what ends up looking like `SELECT 0`, where if an issue occurred it might return `SELECT 3910` that would mean something to that application. You are only going to see the full logic (if any) behind all of it by doing a trace on the commands.

Comment: The version is SQL server 2005, so unfortunately no extended events. I also hesitate to use profiler because of the overhead it might incur (the database server is shared by several applications)

Comment: There is no might about the overhead, Profiler and Extended Events both have their own level of overhead that is seen based on what you are trying to capture. That is the general reason you can filter both down to the database and evens you want, and do not run it forever. Unless you have access to the folks that wrote the application it is your only option. As well, I have run profiler on extremely active systems and there are times it has to be done if you want to find the answer.

Comment: I've contacted the person who made this particular app (he still works for us indirectly on a different project, so I'm in luck). If all else fails, I'll turn to profiler.